# CSP frame-ancestors wildcard usage failing

Tags: html, http-headers, content-security-policy, x-frame-options

I've got a need to whitelist my website from being iframed just for one particular domain.
The url accessing the wildcard will be something like https://app.domain.com/project/123/456

The https://app.domain.com/project/123 section always stays constant but the end will change.

I tried to implement the below frame-ancestor directive but it fails with an error in the browser.

frame-ancestors 'self' https://app.domain.com/project/123/*;

The error I get is

> Refused to frame 'https://yourdomain.cloud/'
> because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy
> directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'
> [https://app.domain.com/project/123/*"](https://app.domain.com/project/123/*%22).

Does the wildcard work only on subdomain, port level?

Comment: It is using the same host-source definition, so it should work. Are there redirects that includes other ancestors?

Answer (score 0):

The wildcard must be leading. Please check this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

> Internet hosts by name or IP address, as well as an optional URL
> scheme and/or port number, separated by spaces. The site's address may
> include an optional **leading** wildcard (the asterisk character,
> '*'), and you may use a wildcard (again, '*') as the port number,
> indicating that all legal ports are valid for the source. Single
> quotes surrounding the host are not allowed